# Access global function from navigator button in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in BackBone. Need to add a navigator button to jqgrid.

```
var bbView = backbone.View.extend({

..............
..............

configureApp : function() {                 

alert("configureApp called");

},
editFunc : function (event){

$("#dataTable").navButtonAdd('#pagerTable',{
                   caption:"",
                   buttonicon:"ui-icon-gear", 
                   onClickButton: function(){ 

                      configureApp();       
                   }, 
                   position:"last"
                });

  }
});
```

While calling 'editFunc', it gives error 'configureApp is not defined'.

Please suggest...

Comment: That doesn't look like a global function definition. It looks like it's a property of some object. So it needs to be `something.configureApp()`.

Comment: I don't know Backbone.js, so I don't know the proper syntax for accessing that function. Maybe `bbview.configureApp()`?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I got the issue, I added the code var self = this; at the starting of configureApp() function, and able to access using self.configureApp();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be written one of two ways.

```
var self = this;

$("#dataTable").navButtonAdd('#pagerTable',{
               caption:"",
               buttonicon:"ui-icon-gear", 
               onClickButton: function(){ 

                  self.configureApp();       
               }, 
               position:"last"
            });
```

**OR**

```
$("#dataTable").navButtonAdd('#pagerTable',{
               caption:"",
               buttonicon:"ui-icon-gear", 
               onClickButton: _.bind(function(){ 

                  this.configureApp();       
               }, this), 
               position:"last"
            });
```

When using the 2nd method, you are telling the function what the context of `this` is and in this case it would be the Backbone.View.